# Open Apple Maps App With Directions from my ios App iOS 9 Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, mkannotation

i have been looking for a lot of tutorials \ Help but doesn't seem to find any , So i once again Come here ....
I would like to Open Apple Maps to get directions and navigate from the user current location to a selected Pin When i press the custom leftCalloutAccessory in my app

I have set up the Button but Cant get the function to work so please'If anyone can guide me through or help me with Code that will be a life saver ! thx

Here is my Code :

```
    import UIKit
    import MapKit
    import CoreLocation

    class MapViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            //==========RegionLocation : =========

            // Init the zoom level
            let coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 31.30, longitude: 34.45)
            let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(125, 125)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, span)
            self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)



            //====================================\\
    }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        //Dispose of resources that can be re created.

            }

        //Mark : Location

        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])



        {
            let location = locations.last

            let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.06, longitudeDelta: 0.06))

            self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

            self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }

        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
        {
            print("Errors: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }

        func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            if annotation is MKUserLocation {
                return nil
            }
            let reuseID = "pin"
            var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseID) as? MKPinAnnotationView
            if(pinView == nil) {
                pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseID)
                pinView!.canShowCallout = true
                pinView!.animatesDrop = true
                pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as UIButton
                let smallSquare = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
                let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: smallSquare))
                button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Car"), forState: .Normal)
                pinView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
            }
            else
            {
                pinView!.annotation = annotation
            }


            return pinView

        }

        func mapView(MapView: MKMapView, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped Control: UIControl) {

            if Control == annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView {

            }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function will open the Apple Maps app and present driving directions from the user's current location to a named destination at a coordinate. The destination name is displayed in the *To:* field of the Maps app.

```
func openMapsAppWithDirections(to coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, destinationName name: String) {
  let options = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
  let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
  let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
  mapItem.name = name // Provide the name of the destination in the To: field
  mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(options)
}
```

You can call this function from your code as follows:

```
func mapView(MapView: MKMapView, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped Control: UIControl) {

  if Control == annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView {
    if let annotation = annotationView.annotation {
      // Unwrap the double-optional annotation.title property or
      // name the destination "Unknown" if the annotation has no title
      let destinationName = (annotation.title ?? nil) ?? "Unknown"
      openMapsAppWithDirections(to: annotation.coordinate, destinationName: destinationName)
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey , First of all after adding the codes to my project I'm immediately prompted to fix requestDirections error to `requestDirections(from: MapView.userLocation.location!.coordinate, to:annotationView.annotation!.coordinate)` if it matters.... Secondly , In the application it-self nothing happens and it does not open apple maps but it does show step by step directions in the debugger

Comment: The `requestDirections` function in my answer demonstrates how to retrieve directions between two coordinates. How you present those directions depends on your application. For example, If you want to show the directions as a line on the map, you can use the `polyline` property of the `MKRoute` object to add a polyline annotation. I hope this helps.

Comment: I understand , thank for your help and i also updated my question to be more accurate of what im looking for.

Comment: I've updated my answer to help you with your renamed and reworded question.

Comment: Hey its working alright ! But its saying its directing to "unknown location" ....is there a way to change that to the annotation Title or something else rather than "unknown location" ?thx

Comment: To provide the name of the destination in the _To:_ field of the Maps app you need to set the value of the `mapItem.name` property. I've updated my answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: Updated the code and ofc it works u are a genuis ;) thanks a lot man

Answer (score 1):

Create extension like this:

```
extension CLLocation {

    func drive() {

        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: self.coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDictionary)

        let launchOptions = [
            MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving
        ]

        MKMapItem.openMaps(with: [MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation(), MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)], launchOptions: launchOptions)

    }
}
```